# Getting the original photo from Picasa Web

Tags: api, google-plus, photos, picasa

.I am using the Picasa API (in python) with a small utility I wrote. When I try to download a high-res photo that I have uploaded, I can't get the original one - the resolution is the same, but the size in bytes is different, as much as half of the size.
 Two months ago, I succeeded downloading the original file with the additional imgmax=d parameter which results in the  elements 
.referencing the original uploaded photo, including all original Exif data, but now, it is impossible
Is there a way to get the original photo (not just the resolution, but also the size) via the API?

Thank You, Jane.